# SQLITE 2 Documentation

Tags: sqlite2

I am trying to find an online documentation for SQLite2. The project I have entered uses SQLite2 and I usually work with SQlite3. I did a google search and didn't find much.

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sqlite docmentation has a specific section for the version 2 API here:
http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html

There is also a section describing the significant changes from V2 to V3.

Comment: Thanks. It was at the very bottom of the page. I didn't notice it. Guess I browse too fast sometimes!